# Differentiation of summation of summation

Tags: derivatives, summation

According to http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf, (45) and (46) (p. 6),

differention of 
$$\alpha = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j $$

with respect to the k-th element of x yields:

$$\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x_k} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_j + \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik} x_i $$

Note that a does not depend on x.

How is this result obtained?

From [differentiation with summation symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217831/differentiation-with-summation-symbol), I understood how to derive one summation.
The function above seems to be of form f(g(x)) to me, so I would apply the chain rule. 
But how can the result contain a + then, indicating some form of the product rule was used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much simpler:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \sum_{i, j} a_{i j} x_i x_j
   = \sum_{i, j} a_{i j}
             \left( \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_k} x_j
                      + x_i \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_k} \right)
   = \sum_j a_{k j} x_j + \sum_i a_{i k} x_i
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that all the terms $a_{ij}x_i x_j$ will vanish when neither $i$ nor $j$ is equal to $k$. So all the remaining terms are of the form $a_{ik}x_i x_k$ and $a_{kj}x_k x_j$, which when differentiated with respect to $x_k$ will yield respectively $a_{ik}x_i$ and $a_{kj} x_j$, as in the announced formula.

Comment: What about when $j=k$?

Comment: $j=k$ corresponds to the case $a_{ik}x_i x_k$

Comment: I mean $i=j$ -- then differentiation will have a different outcome since you are differentiating $a_{kk}x_k^2$.

Comment: then just put $i=k$ in the first kind of terms, or $j=k$ in the second. the factor 2 will appear because you'll get one term of each kind